# SpriteKit: callback when scene is done presenting?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skscene, skview

In SpriteKit, is there a callback when a scene has completed its transition?

It doesn't appear like the [SKView `presentScene`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview) function has a callback.

The alternative is to have the scene manually notify the caller after the scene moves into view, but was hoping there is a cleaner approach with a native callback.

Comment: there is no call back that I am aware of, you need to use the moveFromView on the old scene

Comment: @Knight0fDragon that's what it seems like. please post as an answer so you can get credit! thanks! though you don't need to use the old scene. you can use events from the new scene (e.g., willMove, didMove).

Comment: you can't use the new scene, you have to use the old scene, the new scene fires immediate, which is not what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`presentScene` has no known callback when a scene has finished transitions,  instead, use either `Notification`s or create your own delegate of some kind on your outgoing scenes `func willMove(from:view)` to achieve the desired effect

```
func willMove(from view:SKView)
{
   NotificationCenter.default.post(name: "TRANSITIONCOMPLETE", object: nil)
   //or create a delegate using protocols, assign the delegate, and call it
   delegate?.finishedTransition()
}
```

Note, you must use the outgoingScenes `willMove(from:view)`,  this is the last thing to happen during the transition.  `didMove(to:view)` on the incomingScene is the start of the transition

Comment: correct, though technically, the question asked for notification when the transition concluded so `didMove` is right (and what was used). thanks for helping!

Comment: @Crashalot.... you and I have very different definitions of "concluded".  To me, that is when a transition ends, which is the willMove(fromView)

Comment: you're right, "concluded" is ambiguous. the wording from the question is correct: when the new scene appears.

Comment: ...no it is not ambiguous.  Do you want when the new scene appears, or do you want when the transition completes?  These are 2 different things

Comment: when the new scene appears, as if `presentScene` had a callback when the new scene appeared. thanks!

Comment: ... I do not think you understand how transitions work.  I am going to assume you are using a very specific transition, fading.  If you are using fading and want to know when your scene is on screen, then you need to use a wait action on your incoming scene of 1/2 the duration of your fade followed by the notification.  You then need to set `pauseIncomingScene` to false on your `SKTransition`